# Color librosa waveplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, librosa

I loaded an audio file, generated mfccs feature, created a color array based on the feature data and now would like to color the waveplot over time by the color array. Code below.

```
import librosa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import librosa.display

#load file
filename = librosa.util.example_audio_file()
y, sr = librosa.load(filename)

# generate features
mf = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr)

# create color array 
color = mf.mean(0)
color = color/max(abs(color))
color # array([-1., -0.5655606 , -0.21613305, ..., -1.,-1.,-1.])

# shapes
y.shape;mf.shape;color.shape
#(1355168,) #(20,2647) #(2647,)

# plot waveplot
plt.figure(figsize=(20,4))
librosa.display.waveplot(y,sr=sr,color = ???)
plt.title('Waveplot')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The waveplot function uses the `y` array which is a time series audio array. However, the mfcc features have way fewer rows and I am not sure how to color the waveplot over time based on the mfccs data. Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you provide a Paint/Photoshop mockup of what you mean by coloring the graph? It is not entirely clear...

Comment: You can calculate time from the MFCC frames using `librosa.core.frames_to_time`.

Comment: @jonnor by coloring the graph I mean let the fragment between 0 and 4 seconds be blue and the rest, 4 to 10 seconds, be red. Thanks for suggestion, I will give a try.